# Internet not working after update to 18.04

Tags: networking, internet

After upgrading to 18.04 my LAN and WiFi connection are not working. I am trying to make the LAN connection work again. When I run ping -c3 8.8.8.8 all three packages are received without package loss. Yesterday I thought I fixed the issue by following this: https://superuser.com/questions/756145/ubuntu-14-04-wired-connection-detected-but-no-internet-access. My internet worked, however, after a reboot my LAN connection is not working again an the /etc/resolv.conf is suddenly empty.
So I am connected but when I go to the internet it cannot connect to any server. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I just opened the file and it is all already there:
[ipv4] dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4 dns-search= ignore-auto-dns=true method=auto. What now? (Ps. sorry for the formatting, I have to copy everything myself since I have no internet..)

Comment: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'Lan network profile name'

Comment: And when I try a WiFi network it won't even connect and say activation of network connection failed. While both LAN and WiFi worked before the update to 18.04.

Comment: 'ip route list' returns 'default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 100 169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s25 scope link metric 100 192.168.178.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.1 metric 100'. Does this look correct?

Comment: Ok, I've found my mistake. I was looking in the wrong etc/ folder. So the problem is solved when I add nameserver 8.8.8.8 to etc/resolv.conf. However, after every reboot I have to manually add it now. How can I solve this?